# Java-Stream - grouping by Class<?>

Tags: java, reflection, java-stream

I have an interface `Animal` and several implementations of it:

```java
interface Animal {}

class Cat implements Animal {}

class Dog implements Animal {}

class Hamster implements Animal {}

class Participant {
  private Animal animal;
  private List<String> names;
}
```

I need to group `Animal` objects based on the class type (`Cat`/`Dog`/`Hamster`) and merge `names` lists using streams.

*For example:*

From `originalList` I need to get the `resultList`:

```
  List<Participant> originalList = List.of(
      new Participant(new Cat(), List.of("Leo")),
      new Participant(new Cat(), List.of("Simba")),
      new Participant(new Dog(), List.of("Charlie", "Ralph")),
      new Participant(new Dog(), List.of("Max")),
      new Participant(new Hamster(), List.of("Snowy"))
  );

  List<Participant> resultList = List.of(
      new Participant(new Cat(), List.of("Leo", "Simba")),
      new Participant(new Dog(), List.of("Charlie", "Ralph", "Max")),
      new Participant(new Hamster(), List.of("Snowy"))
  );
```

I was only able to cast the list to a map, but I don't know how to further cast that to a list

```java
Map<Class<? extends Animal>, List<Participant>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it.getAnimal().getClass()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you really want you can access *no-args* constructor by invoking `getConstructor()` on the instance of `Class<T>` but it might throw `NoSuchMethodException` which is checked, and then invoke `newInstance()` which in turn throws a bunch of exceptions, dealing with them inside the lambda isn't a great idea, hence we need to extract this logic into a separate method.

And that's how we can obtain instances of `Cat`, `Dog` and `Hamster` which are needed to create resulting `Participant` objects.

The method responsible for creating a new instance of `Animal` subtypes by the means of reflection might be written like this:

```
public static <T extends Animal> Animal createAnimal(Class<T> animalClass) {
    try {
        return animalClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable create instance of " + animalClass.getSimpleName());
}
```

Which looks scary, but in case if you want to see the full reflection-based solution [*it's here*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tpx).

#### Alternative Approach - defining an auxiliary Record

There's a **better way**, than using reflection.

As *@Holger* has pointed out in the comments, we can define a [*record*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) (or a class) which would wrap an instance of `Animal` and override `equals/hashCode` contract based on the class of animal.

```
record Key(Animal animal) {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return animal.getClass().hashCode();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Key k && k.animal.getClass() == animal.getClass();
    }
}
```

And then we can use this *record* to group *participants* by animal type inside the `groupingBy()`.

```
List<Participant> originalList = List.of(
    new Participant(new Cat(), List.of("Leo")),
    new Participant(new Cat(), List.of("Simba")),
    new Participant(new Dog(), List.of("Charlie", "Ralph")),
    new Participant(new Dog(), List.of("Max")),
    new Participant(new Hamster(), List.of("Snowy"))
);
    
List<Participant> resultList = originalList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        participant -> new Key(participant.getAnimal()),
        Collectors.flatMapping(participant -> participant.getNames().stream(),
            Collectors.toList())
        ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new Participant(entry.getKey().animal(), entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
Participant{animal=CAT, names=[Leo, Simba]}
Participant{animal=DOG, names=[Charlie, Ralph, Max]}
Participant{animal=HAMSTER, names=[Snowy]}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/ttb)

#### Alternative Approach - changing the overall Class-Design

Since your classes `Cat`, `Dog` and `Hamster` completely luck attributes, you can substitute all as well as interface `Animal` with an **enum** (and even you've provided a simplified code and these classes do have attributes, using dummy objects created via *no-args constructor* which are not really meant to represent particular instances of `Animal` doesn't look very clean, so you can have them both - your *classes* and the *enum*, and they will serve different purposes).

```
Animal { CAT, DOG, HAMSTER }
```

And things would become more simpler:

```
List<Participant> originalList = List.of(
    new Participant(Animal.CAT, List.of("Leo")),
    new Participant(Animal.CAT, List.of("Simba")),
    new Participant(Animal.DOG, List.of("Charlie", "Ralph")),
    new Participant(Animal.DOG, List.of("Max")),
    new Participant(Animal.HAMSTER, List.of("Snowy"))
);
    
List<Participant> resultList = originalList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Participant::getAnimal,
        Collectors.flatMapping(participant -> participant.getNames().stream(),
            Collectors.toList())
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new Participant(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
Participant{animal=CAT, names=[Leo, Simba]}
Participant{animal=DOG, names=[Charlie, Ralph, Max]}
Participant{animal=HAMSTER, names=[Snowy]}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/tpw)

Comment: I made this model as the simplest example of a model from a working project, the interface is deliberately used there.

Comment: @NeverSleeps OK, what about instances of `Cat`, etc. do they differ anyhow? I mean are you really creating them using no-arg constructor?

Comment: Yes. So I only need to check the class type itself (`Cat`/`Dog`/`Hamster`)

Comment: @NeverSleeps So, you are OK with using newly created instances of these animals, right?

Comment: Yes. But it is important for me to save the type itself. At the location of `entry.getKey()` I am now getting a compilation error
`Required type: Animal
Provided: Class <capture of ? extends Animal>`

Comment: @NeverSleeps Added a solution using reflection. Full code is accessible via link to online-demo.

Comment: You don’t need this fragile reflection stuff, if you just create a key that uses the `Class` for equality but remembers the `Animal` instance. E.g. see https://jdoodle.com/ia/tt7

Comment: @Holger You're right! Feeling embarrassed. Updated the answer.